# Prevent Daterangepicker from closing when predefined range selected

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

I'm using Dan Grossman's DateRangePicker plugin to provide users with a way to select both predefined and custom date ranges for a specific feature on my site. I have it working, but I have one nagging issue that I have not been able to resolve.

When the user clicks on a predefined date range, the bootstrap dropdown menu closes. This causes the user to have to reopen the date picker and click the "apply" button to execute the function.

I would like the dropdown menu to remain open after a predefined date range has been clicked. Then the user can quickly click the apply button if they are happy with the range.

I have tried the following:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.ranges li', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

This effectively prevents the dropdown from closing, but it doesn't then execute the "clickRange" function in order to set the start and end dates in the appropriate inputs.

Comment: call the "clickRange" function after `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, this has no effect. That dropdown still closes when a predefined date range button is clicked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just show call `show()` function when you select range other than "Custom Range".

You can use following code :

```js
 $(function() {
  var listItem,applyClicked=false;
  /* $(document).on('click', '.ranges li', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
  }); */

  var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
  var end = moment();

  function cb(start, end) {
   /* console.log(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - '
     + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY')); */
   $('#reportrange span').html(
     start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - '
       + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
  }

  $('#reportrange').daterangepicker(
    {
     startDate : start,
     endDate : end,
     ranges : {
      'Today' : [ moment(), moment() ],
      'Yesterday' : [ moment().subtract(1, 'days'),
        moment().subtract(1, 'days') ],
      'Last 7 Days' : [ moment().subtract(6, 'days'),
        moment() ],
      'Last 30 Days' : [ moment().subtract(29, 'days'),
        moment() ],
      'This Month' : [ moment().startOf('month'),
        moment().endOf('month') ],
      'Last Month' : [
        moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'),
        moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month') ]
     }
    }, cb);

  $(".ranges ul li").click(function() {
   listItem = $(this).text();
  });
  $(".range_inputs ").click(function() {
   applyClicked=true;
  });

  $('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
   console.log(listItem +" : "+ applyClicked);
   if(listItem!="Custom Range" && !applyClicked){
    picker.show();
    applyClicked=false;
   }
    
   //ev.preventDefault();

  });

  cb(start, end);

 });
```

```html
<!-- Include Required Prerequisites -->
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.css" />

<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />



<div id="reportrange" class="pull-right"
  style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp; <span></span>
  <b class="caret"></b>
 </div>
```

Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Thanks, Abhijeet. Your answer worked perfectly, and I understand the solution, so that's a bonus. Best!

Comment: I was trying out this solution as it appeared to work initially. However, after you click on the Apply button and then reopen the calendar the undesired affect is back where no matter what you click on the Calendar closes.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with this code where config-demo is id of textbox you can replace your textbox id:

```
$(function () {
     $(document).on('click', '.ranges li', function (e) {
         $("#config-demo").focus();
     });
});
```

Comment: Hi Rakesh, thanks for your input. I think you answered a different problem than the one I was having, but it may have been due to a lack of information in my question.

Comment: Its ok dear . No problem .

Answer (score 0):

[Abhijeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39656393/4306828) does not really work except the initial run, as Elijah pointed out in his [comment.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430504/prevent-daterangepicker-from-closing-when-predefined-range-selected#comment113862251_39656393)

It also depends on text value of the default range option. Which is a terrible programming practice due to it's fragility. In this case, that solution *does* break if you use the widget in multiple languages.

I've developed the following solution, and wanted to share it here;

```js
initDateRangePicker($('input'))

function initDateRangePicker($input) {

  $input.daterangepicker({
    alwaysShowCalendars: true,
    ranges: {
      'Today': [moment(), moment()],
      'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
      'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
      'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
      'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
    }
  })

  $input.on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    if (rangeClicked) picker.show()
  })

  let rangeClicked = false

  // we want picker to remain open when after selecting a custom range
  $('.daterangepicker').not('.custom-events-attached').not('.custom-events-attached')
    // mark picker instance(s) as processed, so we won't attach duplicate events in the future
    .addClass('custom-events-attached')

    // clicking anywhere on the picker will reset our state
    // this is not a problem since this click event will always be fired after `apply.daterangepicker`
    .click(() => rangeClicked = false)

    // selecting one of the ranges will let us know that we want to keep our picker open
    // on the next `apply` event
    .find('.ranges').find('li').click(() => {
      rangeClicked = true
    })
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.5/daterangepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.5/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.5/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="date-range">
```

Comment: Doesn't update date range on custom range